# Uniform distribution modulo 1 and probability

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Define counting function $A(E; N; \omega)$ as the number of terms $x_n, 1\leq n\leq N$, for which $\{x_n\}\in E$.

Then the sequence $\omega=(x_n), n=1,2,...,$ of real numbers is
said to be uniformly distributed modulo 1 (abbreviated u.d. mod 1) if for
every pair $a, b$ of real numbers with $0<a<b<1$ we have
$$\lim\limits_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{A([a,b);N;\omega)}{N}=b-a.$$

Assume we have a real number sequence $(a_n):n\in\mathbb N$, which is u.d. mod 1. It is obvious that for smaller intervals the proportion of fractional parts in those intervals will be smaller. Hence, intuition suggests that some kind of measure $P$ could be introduced to get

$$P\left(\{a_n\}>\frac 1n\right)=1, \quad\text{when }\quad n\rightarrow\infty.$$

I am looking for a reference where this idea is explored. Disproving my intuition for different kind of measures would be welcome too.

I do not want to reinvent the wheel and I am looking for a most common and conventional approach in building this bridge between number and probability theory.

Comment: This seems like it should be trivial from the definition of "u.d. mod 1". No? (I assume you mean something equivalent to "equidistributed sequence").

Comment: My intuition says yes, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel, if someone already did it.

Comment: I don't think this really appropriate for mathoverflow, but the answer is yes: for each $\frac{1}{2} > \varepsilon > 0$ we have $\mathbb{P} \left( \{ a_n \} > \varepsilon \right) \to 1 - 2 \varepsilon$. Taking $\varepsilon$ arbitrarily small we get the desired result.

Comment: Can you give me a reference to this fact?

Comment: In case this is the point of confusion: what do you mean by "probability that $a_n > \epsilon$" here? A sequence doesn't inherently come with a probability! Generally, one would associate the Lebesgue measure, since it's the limit of the empirical measures $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \delta_{a_n}$ when $(a_n)$ is uniformly distributed. Then, indeed, the answer is trivial, since $P(x > \epsilon) = 1-\epsilon$.

Comment: @RonniePavlov thank you very much for the comment. I edited the question and tried to clarify the confusion.

Comment: Presumably, $P(\{a_n\} > \frac{1}{n})$ is meant to be something like $\frac{|\{1 \leq i \leq n | a_i > \frac{1}{n}\}|}{n}$. Or do you specifically want to match the term $a_n$ with the denominator of the fraction $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: @user44191 Classical definition of probability is acceptable. However, does the u.d. mod 1 property and the probability in that matter hold for not fixed numbers?